# Android Studio version 3.1.3 update issue

Tags: android, android-studio-3.1

Today I update the android version 3.1.3 but there are a lot of issue after the update, below are the issue which is showing in the Android Studio.

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.4.0.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.4.0/gradle-4.4.0.pom
    https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.4.0/gradle-4.4.0.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.4.0/gradle-4.4.0.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.4.0/gradle-4.4.0.jar
    https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.4.0/gradle-4.4.0.pom
    https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.4.0/gradle-4.4.0.jar
Required by:
    project :
Open File
```

Comment: you should use a different version for gradle build tools, try 3.1.3

Comment: Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0. error